# Implementing Chrome DevTool Device Mode on website

Tags: html, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, viewport

I used Bootstrap as a responsiveness framework for a web app and I want to add a feature similar to Google chromes **device mode** to preview app responsiveness on different screen sizes.

Since bootstrap uses the `MediaQuery` engine, `width` of the browser determines view modes. I am looking for a solution to switch between different views (mobile, tablet, and large screens) when the browser is on maximized width. I tried to change the `viewport` but I think it should be more than that.

Is there any implementation of the above-mentioned that I can use or any sample?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by wrapping page content in an `iframe` tag and changed the `width` to trigger `mediaQuery`.